# Variable is used by anonymous query but not declared

Tags: php, api, graphql, shopify-api

I am using this library https://github.com/phpclassic/php-shopify to retrieve translations from the Shopify GraphQL API.

Unfortunately I get this error:

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught PHPShopify\Exception\ApiException: message - Variable $gqlGid is used by anonymous query but not declared

Can somebody help to debug this? My code looks like this:

```
    $gqlVariables = array("gqlGid"=>'gid://shopify/OnlineStoreArticle/557585301654');

    $graphQL = <<<Query
    query {
        translatableResource(resourceId: \$gqlGid) {
        resourceId
        translations(locale: "de") {
          key
          value
        }
      }
    }
    Query;

    $data = $shopify->GraphQL->post($graphQL, null, null, $gqlVariables);
```

I have used this library and the Shopify GraphQL API before, without having this issue. I do not know why this is happening.